# How can I get lists of items ignoring blank cells from a column using only excel formula (Without VBA)

Tags: excel

Please see the image which will show my data and expected output.

[image: Data and expected output]

Comment: Just copy it and sort alphabetically. At least if you are not concerned about the order in which they occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula in C2 cell: It is a array formula, so press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` after entering formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$15<>"",ROW($A$2:$A$15)),ROWS($A$2:$A2))-1),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the release of Excel 365 and Dynamic Arrays, this becomes very simple:

```
=FILTER(A:A,(ROW(A:A)>1)*(A:A<>""))
```

- `ROW(A:A)>1` is used to exclude the header,
- `A:A<>""` is used to exclude blanks

Answer (score 0):

And if you are concerned about the order in which they appear. Create another column and insert index values from 1 to n (Fill Down - Series). Then:

-sort by fruit
-delete the numbers in index column where there is no fruit (they should be in the bottom)
-sort by index from smallest to largest.

[image]