# Excel - Formula that skips rows if two IF logical tests aren't met

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a table with all the data (in a tab called 'Master') which I want to get information from if it meets two criteria, and put that in another tab.

The Master tab basically laid out like this:

Name in A, Criteria 1 in B and Criteria 2 in C

```
Ben           Yes           Yes

Bob           No            Yes

Rob           Yes           Yes
```

This is the formula I have so far:

```
=IF(AND(Master!$B1="Yes",Master!$C1="Yes"),Master!$A1,"")
```

What I want it to do drag this formula down in my second tab so it will (in the above example) pick out Ben, ignore Bob and then in the next row pick out Rob.

Comment: is the result not accomplished if you drag down the formula you already have?

Comment: Annoyingly not, as then it will just look in B2, B3, etc... and I'll have a blank row in my second tab where the formula is rather than a return. So in the above example, I'll get "Ben", Blank Row, "Rob" (hope that makes sense)

Comment: You can get the column with the empty rows you are getting as a helping column and apply the index formula as described here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432821/how-can-i-get-lists-of-items-ignoring-blank-cells-from-a-column-using-only-excel

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in cell D1 and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, then drag down in the column.
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$7,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$7="Yes",IF($C$1:$C$7 ="Yes",ROW($B$1:$B$7)-ROW($B$1)+1)),ROWS($B$1:$B1))),"")`

You can adjust all the 10's to whatever your last row # is (wasn't sure how many rows your table takes up).

You will also have to add the `Master!` sheet reference in front of all cell references.

This will return a list of names in column D without having any gaps or spaces.
It first checks if Column B = 'Yes' and then if column C = 'Yes'.